# how to exclude a css from clientlib in CQ

Tags: aem

I am using single clientlib for all the pages in my site. Only for one page, i need to exclude one css file from clientlib.
In this case, Should I create a different clientlib and a different template for that page ?
Or 
Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the clientlibs are determined by the css.txt and js.txt files, and these are just hard-coded lists. The clientlibs are assembled when the application is deployed so modifying their contents at run-time would be problematic.

So you are going to need multiple clientlibs to describe the two different lists of css files. Keep in mind that you can use "embeds", "depends", and "categories" relationships to make referencing them easier. Imagine two simple client libs named A and B - A contains A.css and B contains B.css.

Now imagine I have two web pages: Cats.html and Dogs.html. Cats needs both style sheets, but Dogs only needs B.css. To achieve this, I can give clientlib A a category of just "cats" and clientlib B a category of both "cats" and "dogs".

This way when I get my clientlibs for the Cats page using category "cats", I'll get both style sheets. And when I use category "dogs", I will only get B.css.

There is a good explanation here: http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/clientlibs-explained-example/

Comment: Thanks @jwepurchase for the reply.

Comment: Actually I need file1.css,file2.css,file3.css,file4.css in same order for other pages and need to exclude file3.css alone for a single page. Need to maintain the same order ; otherwise content is getting overlapped. Can u please help on that?

Comment: Option 1 - use lots of clientibs. Make 3 client libs: (1, 2), (3), and (4). Then make two more that contain no files and just dependencies of the first - one will depend on (1,2),(3), and (4); the other will just depend on (1,2), and (4). Option 2: two clientlibs with absolute paths in your css.txt file.